# Not setting default locale in Rails 3.1.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, i18n-gem

Not setting default_locale in Rails 3.1.3

application.rb:

```
config.i18n.default_locale = :en
```

I have got 3 locales (en,es and ca)
And when i go to my console:

```
I18n.locale => :ca # I guess the first one in the array
```

I am using Gettext. Somebody got a clue what it could be?

Bundle:

```
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using Ascii85 (1.0.1) 
Using ZenTest (4.5.0) 
Using multi_json (1.0.4) 
Using activesupport (3.1.3) 
Using builder (3.0.0) 
Using i18n (0.6.0) 
Using activemodel (3.1.3) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using rack (1.3.6) 
Using rack-cache (1.1) 
Using rack-mount (0.8.3) 
Using rack-test (0.6.1) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.0.3) 
Using actionpack (3.1.3) 
Using mime-types (1.17.2) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.10) 
Using mail (2.3.0) 
Using actionmailer (3.1.3) 
Using arel (2.2.1) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.31) 
Using activerecord (3.1.3) 
Using activeresource (3.1.3) 
Using addressable (2.2.6) 
Using adyen (1.3.0) 
Using airbrake (3.0.5) 
Using ansi (1.3.0) 
Using autotest (4.4.6) 
Using xml-simple (1.1.1) 
Using aws-ses (0.4.4) 
Using bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1) 
Using bluecloth (2.2.0) 
Using bulksms (0.5.2) 
Using bundler (1.0.21) 
Using highline (1.6.2) 
Using net-ssh (2.2.1) 
Using net-scp (1.0.4) 
Using net-sftp (2.0.5) 
Using net-ssh-gateway (1.1.0) 
Using capistrano (2.9.0) 
Using capistrano-ext (1.2.1) 
Using nokogiri (1.5.0) 
Using ffi (1.0.9) 
Using childprocess (0.2.2) 
Using json_pure (1.6.1) 
Using rubyzip (0.9.4) 
Using selenium-webdriver (2.8.0) 
Using xpath (0.1.4) 
Using capybara (1.1.1) 
Using carrierwave (0.5.8) 
Using chunky_png (1.2.5) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.1.2) 
Using execjs (1.2.9) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using fssm (0.2.7) 
Using sass (3.1.10) 
Using compass (0.12.alpha.0) 
Using compass-960-plugin (0.10.4) 
Using rest-client (1.6.7) 
Using couchrest (1.1.2) 
Using couchrest_model (1.1.2) 
Using daemons (1.0.10) 
Using diff-lcs (1.1.3) 
Using e164 (0.3.1) 
Using excon (0.7.12) 
Using factory_girl (2.3.0) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using json (1.6.5) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.14.6) 
Using railties (3.1.3) 
Using factory_girl_rails (1.4.0) 
Using multipart-post (1.1.3) 
Using faraday (0.7.5) 
Using faraday_middleware (0.7.0) 
Using fast_gettext (0.6.2) 
Using formatador (0.2.1) 
Using ruby-hmac (0.4.0) 
Using fog (1.1.1) 
Using rails (3.1.3) 
Using formtastic (2.0.0.rc5) 
Using gem_plugin (0.2.3) 
Using geocoder (1.1.0) 
Using geokit (1.6.0) 
Using locale (2.0.5) 
Using gettext (2.1.0) 
Using gettext_i18n_rails (0.3.0) 
Using gravatar (1.0) 
Using guard (1.0.0) 
Using guard-rspec (0.6.0) 
Using haml (3.1.4) 
Using haml-rails (0.3.4) 
Using hashie (1.1.0) 
Using jquery-rails (1.0.17) 
Using kaminari (0.12.4) 
Using kgio (2.6.0) 
Using launchy (2.0.5) 
Using libv8 (3.3.10.2) 
Using metaclass (0.0.1) 
Using subexec (0.1.0) 
Using mini_magick (3.3) 
Using mocha (0.10.0) 
Using money (4.0.1) 
Using mongrel (1.2.0.pre2) 
Using multi_xml (0.4.1) 
Using nifty-generators (0.4.6) 
Using ruby-rc4 (0.1.3) 
Using pdf-reader (1.0.0) 
Using ttfunk (1.0.3) 
Using prawn (0.12.0) 
Using rack-protection (1.1.4) 
Using raindrops (0.8.0) 
Using redis (2.2.2) 
Using redis-namespace (1.0.3) 
Using sinatra (1.3.1) 
Using vegas (0.1.8) 
Using resque (1.19.0) 
Using resque_mailer (2.0.2) 
Using rspec-core (2.8.0) 
Using rspec-expectations (2.8.0) 
Using rspec-mocks (2.8.0) 
Using rspec (2.8.0) 
Using rspec-rails (2.8.1) 
Using ruby-ole (1.2.11.2) 
Using sexp_processor (3.0.7) 
Using ruby_parser (2.3.1) 
Using sass-rails (3.1.5) 
Using simple_oauth (0.1.5) 
Using spreadsheet (0.6.5.9) 
Using state_machine (1.0.2) 
Using steak (2.0.0) 
Using therubyracer (0.9.8) 
Using turn (0.8.3) 
Using twitter (1.7.2) 
Using uglifier (1.0.3) 
Using unicorn (4.1.1) 
Using useragent (0.4.6)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add to `application.rb` this line `config.i18n.locale = :ca` and Rails will set default locale. It is working for me in production server, but I set `:ru` locale

Comment: Hey this is working indeed. But I seriously dont like the solution. Because default_locale is the variable to set... Anyway I accept your answer :)

Answer (score 8):

Did you uncomment the following line ?

```
config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
```

Rails will take translated text from this location only. But this is for Rails specific translation gem. If you want to set default locale for gettext you need to set as below

Add it to environment.rb

```
I18n.supported_locales = Dir[File.join(RAILS_ROOT, "locale/*")].collect{|v| File.basename(v)}
```

Test in a rails console

```
 ::I18n.locale = 'en'
```

You can verify this by the following gettext method

```
GetText.locale.to_s
```

Basically I set languages by setting `I18n.locale = 'en'` or any other locale. You can set the default language based on browser preferred language also. You can also force the language to set locale in (gettext) by passing lang='ca', etc. All you need is to use `:before_filter`. Call the below method in that filter

```
def set_default_language
    languages   = get_browser_preferred_languages_hash(request.env["HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE"])
    @locale     = languages.blank? ? 'en' : app_preferred_language(languages, params[:lang])[0..1]
    I18n.locale = @locale || 'en'
end

  def get_browser_preferred_languages_hash(languages)
    # no language accepted
    return [] if languages.blank?
    # parse Accept-Language
    accepted = languages.split(",")
    accepted = accepted.map { |l| l.strip[0..1]}
  end

  def app_preferred_language(languages,forced_lang)
    unless forced_lang.blank?
      return forced_lang.class == Array ? forced_lang[0] : forced_lang       
    end
    return 'en' if languages.blank?
    @matched_lang = ''
    languages.each do |lang|
      @matched_lang = support_languages_hash.values.detect{|ele| ele[0..1] == lang}
      break if !@matched_lang.blank?
    end
    return @matched_lang.blank? ? 'en' : @matched_lang
  end

  def support_languages_hash
    GetText.locale
    { _('English')    => 'en-US',
      _('Spanish')    => 'es-419',
      _('Catalan')    => 'ca' }
  end
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is it, but maybe you're overriding `config.i18n.default_locale` in your environment file, ie. `environments/development.rb`.

A good start point would be to look for all the occurences of `I18n.locale`, `I18n.default_locale`, and related values by grepping. I would start by `grep 'locale' app -rn` (r for recursive, n to show line numbers), then do it again in the project root.

Comment: That worked for me! I really don't know why, but I had to declared the locale in my test environment.

Answer (score 1):

I'm learning rails. I'm following Pragmatic Agile Web Development with Rails.
I was just trying and trying to make localization work and it just didn't work. After some time, I have noticed that in my tests the locale was correct. Weird.
Then I realized that the view was cached. So try to remove files in rails_app_path/tmp.

Cheers!

Comment: I just spent probably 2 hours banging my head against the wall trying to figure out why `config.i18n.default_locale` was not being respected in my app. This is what fixed it. Ridiculous. But thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is probably related to using Gettext. If I'm not mistaken it uses its own mechanisms for storing and fetching the locale and I suppose it simply doesn't respect any default_locale settings. In case some of you got here because you have had similar problems without Gettext. For you guys I can say that at least with latest stable rails release default_locale works just fine. You have probably redefined it and or explicitly set the locale somewhere. Grep your project for references:

```
grep -rn default_locale . 
grep -rn I18n.locale .
```

or smhtn..

Another thing to remember is that server restart is probably needed for the new default_locale setting to have effect.